# How to store the past memory usage of the computer?

Tags: windows-10, memory

I have a Windows 10 machine, 64 bit.

Is there a way to store the memory usage plots (CPU usage, RAM etc.) that one can find on the `Task Manager` or on programs like `Process Explorer`?

I would like to produce a plot of the memory usage of the past day (say) and correlate that with the speed, efficiency etc. of other scripts I am running on the computer.

Comment: You mean like, when you go to the tab Performance in Task Manager, and hit the link at the very bottom of that tab which says: Open Resource Monitor? You can however not access past events, but only measure from that moment forward.

Comment: a) I would like past data. b) I would like to download the data in some format (say csv) so that I can plot it again only in the interval of time that I care about.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[You can use Performance Monitor to create data collector sets, which include logging options.](https://www.windowscentral.com/how-use-performance-monitor-windows-10#use_data_collector_sets) Resource Monitor in Task Manager is realtime data, but doesn't have a logging feature.

The key tidbits for your purposes are:

Open Perfmon:

> Open Start, do a search for Performance Monitor, and click the result.
>   Use the Windows key + R keyboard shortcut to open the Run command, type perfmon, and click OK to open.
>   Use the Windows key + X keyboard shortcut to open the Power User menu, select Computer Management, and click on Performance.

Create a Data Collector Set:

> While in Performance Monitor, expand Data Collector Sets.
>   Right-click "User Defined", select New, and click on Data Collector Set. Type a descriptive name for the new set.
>   Select the Create manually (Advanced) option.
>   Click Next.

Set your logging rules:

> Select Create data logs and check the Performance counter option, but notice that you can also use other options as needed.
>   Click Next.

Perfmon.exe has been around for a long time, but the Windows 10 version is a little different than prior versions.   The link is to a complete guide on using it to diagnose problems, and contains the above instructions at the associated label when you click it.

Comment: It is considered bad practice on SuperUser to link to an external source. The link may expire at some point which invalidates your answer. If you copy/paste the necessary bits from that link, I'll vote your answer up. Until then, no vote from me.

Comment: and.... upvoted. :)